# How does "static reflection" work in java? (ex. in mockito or easymock)

Tags: c#, java, reflection, easymock, mockito

I'm a .NET guy - and I mainly code in C#.

Since C# 3.0, we can leverage lambda expressions and expression trees to use [static reflection](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/gabrielschenker/archive/2009/02/03/dynamic-reflection-versus-static-reflection.aspx). For example, it is possible to implement `GetMethodName` in the following snippet to return the name of the method passed in parameter:

```
string methodName = GetMethodName( o => o.DoSomething());
Console.WriteLine(methodName); // displays "DoSomething"
```

Now, when I look at Mockito samples (or EasyMock ones) in the java world, I see:

```
LinkedList mockedList = mock(LinkedList.class);
when(mockedList.get(0)).thenReturn("first");
```

**How does it work?**

How does the `when` method work ? How does it interpret `mockedList.get(0)` as *a call to the get method with 0 passed as parameter* and not as a value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mocking libraries don't typically work with expression trees. They build a type which implements the appropriate interface and responds to method calls either by recording them or validating them and returning the preprogrammed responses. This is usually done with either a proxy (e.g. [RealProxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.remoting.proxies.realproxy.aspx) in .NET, [Proxy](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) in Java) or with dynamic code generation.

In the case of EasyMock, it uses `Proxy` (for interfaces, anyway), as you can see in the source code: look at `org.easymock.internal.JavaProxyFactory`.

Comment: Proxy on works with interfaces. Real mocking frameworks to their own code generation.

Comment: In .NET, strongly typed mocking frameworks use expression trees (cf. Moq & Rhino mocks) and indeed dynamic proxies. But here it's still unclear to me how (even with proxies) you can safely setup the mock. What if I type "when(mockedList.get(0) + mockedList.get(2)).thenReturn(42)"?

Comment: Rhino Mocks existed long before expression trees did. It may use expression trees *now* in some cases, but it doesn't *always* do so. (It still works in .NET 2.0.) If you make another call to the mock before specifying the result of the last one, the results depend on the mode of the mock.

Comment: (IIRC, anyway.) In a strict mode, the recording phase will fail because you haven't specified the appropriate return value. In some other modes, it will return the default value. It's entirely up to the mocking framework. It just sees two get(...) calls followed by a thenReturn() call.

Comment: @Tom: You need code generation to mock classes, but not all mocking frameworks even *allow* that, at least out of the box. If you're only mocking interfaces, Proxy is fine. I can't remember the last time I mocked a class :)

Answer (score 4):

Java mock libraries usually work like this:

When you create a mock, an actual proxy is created (be it from an interface or a sub-class), the instance is in "recording mode". This means that any subsequent call is recorded (method name, parameters, return expected). Notice that the proxy in recording mode does actually nothing but record the calls. There is no reflection per-se involved. No metadata discovery, etc. Of course these libraries do some tricks (such as storing invocations in a thread-local variable to handle methods that return void) but the idea remains the same.

Then, when the "replay mode" is started, the mock instance simply checks the expectations from the list of invocations (method+parameters & return values).

Answer (score 2):

I’ve never worked with mockito or easymock but I don’t think the call does what you think it does. It does not interpret `mockedList.get(0)` in any special way. The method `get` is executed on the `mockedList` object normally, and the *result* of that is handed in to `when`.

Answer (score 1):

`mockedList.get(0)` is the syntax for a method call, and does exactly that. What that method does is not exactly clear. `mockedList`'s runtime type will be a subclass of `LinkedList` returned by the `mock` method, which can be implemented how ever the mocking framework sees fit.